# Image Carousel Not Displaying Images from Database Using Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display images in a carousel by retrieving their path which is stored in an SQL Server table.

Below is my ASPX:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Rgallary" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgId" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("filename", "~/SlideImages/{0}") %>' />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is my Code-behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        bindslide();
    }
}


public void bindslide()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SlideShowTable", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Rgallary.DataSource = ds;
    Rgallary.DataBind();

    conn.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Below is my table structure also:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlideShowTable] (
[ID]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[filename]  VARCHAR (250) NULL,
[imageDesc] VARCHAR (250) NULL,
[groupNo]   INT           NULL
```

);

This is what appears when I inspect the div:

[image: snip1]

When I run the project, the page displays, but no images are currently being displayed.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: check you image **url** by **inspecting element** to check path

Comment: @Curiousdev Hi, I've inspected the page, & posted what I found above. The path makes sense I think. And when I hover over those image links when inspecting, a thumbnail of the image is displayed

Comment: is your image path is right? second thing **<div class="item">** remove one div because class="item" applied for two times and it will stop working check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/198/) for same

Comment: @Curiousdev Yes, the image path is correct. I've used this ImageURL in other parts of my project. It is only when I try to integrate it into a carousel that I have problems with it. I have also removed the div class="item active"

Comment: @Curiousdev I have just removed the carousel div's, and kept the repeater to see if the images would then be displayed, and yes they are being displayed when I do this, so the path is correct

Comment: make sure your console does not throw any errors and secondly check if there is any div which is display none behind or after carousel div because seems like all things is correct it should be work as we are expecting or do you have any way to show me the live page deployed anywhere it would be better to identify the root cause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133105/discussion-between-curiousdev-and-sweg).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following statement, Eval() is better used for one way binding. Also you can change control from asp:Image to plain HTML img

```
<img alt="" style='height: 75px; width: 75px' src='<%# Eval("~/SlideImages/"+ filename) %>'
```

Comment: This solution does not work. I have copied it, and the error I am getting is 'filename' does not exist in this context.